# How to eliminate "blank" rows that show up after importing an Excel file using pd.read_excel()

Tags: python, pandas

I read in an Excel file from an external source:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('https://www.sharkattackfile.net/spreadsheets/GSAF5.xls')
```

When I call `df.tail()`, I see that there are 25,841 rows in this dataframe.

[image]

Also, notably, I see that there is a value of 'xx' in the Case Number column.  This is **not valid** data.

But, looking at the file itself, I see that there are only 6807 rows of **valid data**:

[image]

How do I get a dataframe that only has the valid data (i.e. rows 1-6807), noting that as cases are added to this file, the range would need to be dynamic?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use pandas DataFrame's `replace` function, then do `dropna` to drop every `np.nan` values.

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html

```
DataFrame.replace('', np.nan)
DataFrame.replace('xx', np.nan)
DataFrame.dropna()
```